# xamarin forms plugin for create phone number entry

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

is there is any plugin for Enter phone number with leading country code in xamarin forms if not is there is any straight way to make this with forms 
like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no Plugin for such request.
However, you can accomplish that with a combination of several plugins.

1 - You need to display a Popup Page, for that you can use this simple nuget package - [https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup](http://RG.Plugins.Popup)

2 - You simply have to make your listview, and then when pressing an item, concatenate the Country Code Id to your Entry.